# What do these errors mean in sysbench disk test?

Tags: linux, disk, flash-memory

I have been running a continuous test of sysbench disk tests on my Linux system that uses compact flash.  I am seeing some errors in the output, as shown below.  What do these errors mean exactly?  Do they mean that some of the disk reads failed?  The part itself is an industrial grade part and supports SMART, and SMART reported no unrecoverable ECC failures.

The command I was using to run the test was:

```
while true; do sysbench --num-threads=16 --test=fileio --file-total-size=3500M --file-test-mode=rndrw prepare; sysbench --num-threads=16 --test=fileio --file-total-size=500M --file-test-mode=rndrw run; sync; sysbench --num-threads=16 --test=fileio --file-total-size=3500M --file-test-mode=rndrw cleanup; done
```

Sample output:

```
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

128 files, 28000Kb each, 3500Mb total
Creating files for the test...
FATAL: Failed to write file! errno = 28 (¦?¦)
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 16

Extra file open flags: 0
128 files, 3.9062Mb each
500Mb total file size
Block size 16Kb
Number of random requests for random IO: 10000
Read/Write ratio for combined random IO test: 1.50
Periodic FSYNC enabled, calling fsync() each 100 requests.
Calling fsync() at the end of test, Enabled.
Using synchronous I/O mode
Doing random r/w test
Threads started!
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 127 pos: 2965504 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 127 pos: 540672 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 130 pos: 655360 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 129 pos: 2441216 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 129 pos: 475136 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 128 pos: 2588672 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 126 pos: 2588672 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 127 pos: 2899968 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 125 pos: 3309568 errno = 0 (T¦v¦)
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 126 pos: 49152 errno = 0 (¦v¦0R0¦¦¦v¦R0¦¦u¦¦Q0¦T¦Q0¦T¦v¦)
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 125 pos: 1097728 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to read file! file: 126 pos: 606208 errno = 0 ()
FATAL: Failed to write file! file: 125 pos: 3440640 errno = 28 ()
FATAL: Failed to wrisysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bug in sysbench. I found a similar one here titled: [Running 'prepare' in fileio test with --file-extra-flags=direct fails](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sysbench/+bug/1043987).

*excerpt*

```
./sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=1G --file-test-mode=rndrw --max-time=18000 --max-requests=0 --num-threads=4 --rand-init=on --file-num=2 --file-fsync-freq=0 --file-block-size=16384 --report-interval=10 --file-extra-flags=direct prepare
sysbench 0.5: multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark

2 files, 524288Kb each, 1024Mb total
Creating files for the test...
Extra file open flags: 3
Creating file test_file.0
FATAL: Failed to write file! errno = 9 (Bad file descriptor)
```

I'd file a bug with the SysBench project. You can do so here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/sysbench

Specifically there's a [link on the side (right) for reporting bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sysbench/+filebug).

Comment: Thanks I submitted a report.  If it turns out to be a bug I'll mark your answer as correct.